# R multi-file operation

Tags: r, data.table

First I load table from the txt file and then I perform several transformations on the table:

```
directory <- 'path'

setwd(directory)


data <- read.table("sample.txt", header=TRUE)

data2 <- data[,c(1,2,3,5,7,8)]

data2$cb <- paste(data2$c,data2$b,sep = ".")

finaldata <- data2[,c(7,1,2,3,4,5,6)]
```

The problem is that I have about 100 of such txt files and I need to automate that process.

I start by listing files like this:

```
filenames <- list.files(path=getwd(),pattern = "*.txt")
```

But now I dont have any idea how it should work. Should i do it in for loop or is there any other way?

Im new in R and this is my first post, so I ask for your understanding.

Comment: Googling "r read multiple files" returns lots and lots (and lots!) of results. Try something from one of those answers and ask a question about something specific if you get stuck.

Answer (score -2):

```
for (i in 1:length(filenames)) {

  data <- read.table(filenames[i], header=TRUE)

  ...


}
```

Comment: This is a good use case for a lapply rather than a for loop as you probably want the results to be in a single list that you can manipulate

Comment: I want the results to be saved as separate txt files with new names or overwritten.

Comment: You can certainly get the desired result with a for loop (see ?write.table). You might also be interested in taking a look at the "apply" family of R functions.

Comment: @Tetley: Post an example (two or three small files) and describe what you are hoping to accomplish, and do pay attention to proper capitalization and placement of apostrophe's. Also ... I suspect this a duplicate so first do a good faith search and say how you searched and what answers might not have completely addressed any special requirements. As you can see already, failing to describe the goals of this effort may not get you an ontarget answer.